# How to stop Ember.Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression escaping apostrophes

Tags: ember.js

I'm fairly new to Ember, but I'm on v1.12 and struggling with the following problem.

- I'm making a template helper
- The helper takes the bodies of tweets and HTML anchors around the hashtags and usernames.

The paradigm I'm following is:

1. use `Ember.Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(value);` to escape the input text
2. do logic
3. use `Ember.Handlebars.SafeString(value);`

However, 1. seems to escape apostrophes. Which means that any sentences I pass to it get escaped characters. How can I avoid this whilst making sure that I'm not introducing potential vulnerabilities?

**Edit: Example code**

```
export default Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper(function(value){
  // Make sure we're safe kids.
  value = Ember.Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(value);
  value = addUrls(value);
  return new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString(value);
});
```

Where `addUrls`is a function that uses a RegEx to find and replace hashtags or usernames. For example, if it were given `#emberjs foo` it would return `<a href="blah">#emberjs</a> foo`.

The result of the above helper function would be displayed in an Ember (HTMLBars) template.

Answer (score 0):

`escapeExpression` is designed to convert a string into the representation which, when inserted in the DOM, with escape sequences translated by the browser, will result in the original string. So

```
"1 < 2"
```

is converted into

```
"1 &lt; 2"
```

which when inserted into the DOM is displayed as

```
1 < 2
```

If `"1 < 2"` were inserted directly into the DOM (eg with `innerHTML`), it would cause quite a bit of trouble, because the browser would interpret `<` as the beginning of a tag.

So `escapeExpression` converts ampersands, less than signs, greater than signs, straight single quotes, straight double quotes, and backticks. The conversion of quotes is not necessary for text nodes, but could be for attribute values, since they may enclosed in either single or double quotes while also containing such quotes.

Here's the list used:

```
var escape = {
  "&": "&amp;",
  "<": "&lt;",
  ">": "&gt;",
  '"': "&quot;",
  "'": "&#x27;",
  "`": "&#x60;"
};
```

I don't understand why the escaping of the quotes should be causing you a problem. Presumably you're doing the `escapeExpression` because you want characters such as `<` to be displayed properly when output into a template using normal double-stashes `{{}}`. Precisely the same thing applies to the quotes. They may be escaped, but when the string is displayed, it should display fine.

Perhaps you can provide some more information about input and desired output, and how you are "printing" the strings and in what contexts you are seeing the escaped quote marks when you don't want to.

Comment: Thanks for your response and explanation. I've added some sample code and example which I hope helps.

Comment: In you case, would it not be the right approach to call `addUrls` before calling `escapeExpression`? You don't want `addUrls` to have to deal with escaped strings.

Comment: but then the links that `addUrls` adds will be escaped into text rather than links?

Comment: Provide a specific example of desired input and output.

Comment: "That's great! #cool" -> "That's great! <a href="http://twitter.com/search?q=%23cool">#cool</a>"

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. 

The `That's great!` is returned as part of the string as I've shown above.